# How to I effectively chain RxJS Observables

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, rxjs, observable

I know this question has been asked a few times in various forms on here but I'm struggling to get this to do exactly what I want.

To give some context, I have a file upload service in NodeJS which stores images in a temporary folder. I then have some functions to resize the image(s) to regular web size and a thumbnail then save to an upload folder, then another function to delete the temporary file. All three of these functions return Observables.

What I want is to run these observables in sequence e.g.

```js
observableA().subscribe((result) => //do something here ) // Resize the photo
observableB().subscribe((result) => //do something here ) // Create a thumbnail
observableC().subscribe((result) => //do something here ) // Delete the temporary file
```

I want to ensure A and B have completed before executing C (deleting the temp folder). I don't want to nest the Observables. Both A and B return some data which I want.

Which is the best rxJS operator to achieve this?

Comment: use the combine operator of rxjs

Comment: check `concat()` operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `forkJoin` to combine first 2 observables (they will run in parallel).
Then use `switchMap` to switch to 3rd observable.

```
import { of, timer, forkJoin } from "rxjs";
import { switchMap, delay, map } from "rxjs/operators";

const observableA = of("resized photo").pipe(delay(300));
const observableB = of("thumbnail").pipe(delay(250));
const observableC = of("temp deleted").pipe(delay(100));

const result = forkJoin(observableA, observableB).pipe(
  switchMap(([resultA, resultB]) => {
    console.log(resultA, resultB);
    console.log('now to observableC');
    return observableC.pipe(map(resultC => [resultA, resultB, resultC]));
  })
);
result.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Check it out on [stakblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/st61406287) (don't forget to open the console to see the `console.log` outputs).

RxJS docs also have a handy page that helps to chose right operator for the job: [operator-decision-tree](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/operator-decision-tree)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `flatMap` which is in a sense `then` for observables keeping in mind flatMap actually performs a function.

```
this._myService.do1()
  .flatMap(function(x){return functionReturningObservableOrPromise(x)})
  .flatMap(... return observable here tooo)
  .subscribe(get your data)
```

Comment: Getting this error when I try this: Property 'flatMap' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'.

Comment: @RobBailey try `mergeMap`

Comment: you'll have to import it from `import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap'`

Answer (score 0):

To preserve the order you should use the `concatMap` operator and you use the `tap` operator for side effects like so:

```
observableA()
  .pipe(
    concatMap(() => observable().pipe(tap(() => /* add some sides effects for this obs. */ )),
    tap(() => /* or add some sides effects here or somewhere else */ )),
    concatMap(() => observableC())
  )
  .subscribe();
```